# Preposition ‘to’ followed by gerund in Steinbeck: “started the little wind to moving among the leaves”

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, causative-verbs, predicate-frames

Q.1. This is a sentence by John Steinbeck. I don’t understand the verb construction of the preposition ‘to’ followed by a gerund instead of by an infinitive. What’s the explanation?

> Evening of a hot day started the little wind **to moving** among the leaves. The shade climbed up the hills toward the top. On the sand banks the rabbits sat as quietly as little gray, sculptured stones.

[*Of Mice and Men*](https://www.google.com.br/books/edition/Of_Mice_and_Men/jpqCEAAAQBAJ?hl=pt-BR&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+the+little+wind+to+moving+among+the+leaves%22&pg=PT11&printsec=frontcover)

Q.2. And does this version have the same meaning as  Steinbeck’s?

> Evening of a hot day started the little wind **that moved** among the leaves.

Comment: (Q1) '[It] started the little wind moving among the leaves' is the standard version. This might be justified as a 'literary' form, but it's hard to find another example; it sounds rather like Irish English. // (Q2) I'd prefer 'had started' here.

Comment: Per @MarcInManhattan, sounds like a rural dialect - plain talk. *Moved* is about equal to moving, but a one-time event.

Comment: *Evening started the wind to moving* means the same as *Evening started the wind moving*. Does the second sentence here make sense to you?

Comment: I'm reminded of the archaic a-Vin' usage: 'The wind set the vanes a-spinnin'.' 'The wind set the vanes to spinning.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You **should** be thus reminded; Steinbeck used *started* in the common way all the time, but he also used it differently in a few places. “But before Ma ate, she put the big round wash tub on the stove and started the fire to roaring." and "...but it was a man's voice that started her awake" are from *Grapes of Wrath*.  "Suddenly her eyes glazed and her back arched like a spring and the blood started to her cheeks." is from *East of Eden*.  "The house cracked, and although he had been listening for sounds, Pat started violently." is from *Pastures of Heaven*.

Comment: @tchrist: This is a bit more *your* specialist subject. Is there any direct connection between  'The wind set the vanes a-spinnin'.' 'The wind set the vanes to spinning.' as flagged up by Edwin, or is it just that they colonised the same "syntactic space" in different ages?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## You got me to thinking...

Thanks for your question, Mónica; it definitely made me think—by which I
mean that it **got me *to* thinking**.

Now that’s a perfectly unremarkable
use that you hear all the time, even though you don’t **need** the *to*
preposition. I could have just said that it got me thinking—or that it got
me to think. Same thing.

Why did Steinbeck use the *to* if he didn’t need to? Because it’s how (some)
people once talked in a certain time and place, so it conveys that same
sense of time and place.  In America during the 1800s and early 1900s, you came upon this
construction from time to time.

It wasn’t regional speech, either; it happened all over the country, and it wasn’t simply uneducated speech either; it appears in the U.S. Congressional Record from those times. I’ll provide citations later on down below, including some recent ones even.

### Grammar Bits

“Making something do something” is actually a type of [causative
construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative), the kind of thing
you see whenever you:

- ...make someone/something do whatever.
- ...have someone/something do whatever.
- ...let someone/something do whatever.
- ...cause someone/something to do whatever.
- ...get someone/something to do whatever.
- ...help someone/something to do whatever.
- ...help someone/something do whatever.

But it’s more than that.  Using the verb *start* adds in an [inchoative (or
inceptive) aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inchoative_aspect) for
initiating the activity, and the *-ing* form of the verb following adds the
continuous aspect for showing that this activity is an ongoing one, not a
completed one.

And it’s the same thing that you see happening with your Steinbeck
quotation, too.

> Evening of a hot day started the little wind to moving among the leaves.

Let’s whittle that down to its key elements, then go through some rewrites:

- Evening started the wind to moving.
- Evening made the wind start moving.
- Evening got the wind to start moving.

Notice how that’s not really the same sense as in your proposed rewrite:

> Evening of a hot day started the little wind that moved among the leaves.

That’s because the evening **made** the wind start moving. The action it
caused or initiated was the verb *moving*.

Steinbeck did the same thing in *The Grapes of Wrath* when he wrote:

> But before Ma ate, she put the big round wash tub on the stove and started the fire to roaring.

Whittled down and rewritten, that’s like:

- Ma started the fire to roaring.
- Ma got the fire to start roaring.
- Ma made the fire start to roar.
- Ma made the fire start roaring.

## Citations

So although you’re more apt to come upon this in American writing from the
1800s, it does show up from time to time even now as the first couple
citations show.

- [What started me to doing this was that this guy named Cowboy wanted to go somewhere and he didn’t have nobody to watch his stuff.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sidewalk/CCN-17p__eUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=PA139&printsec=frontcover)
  *Sidewalk*, Mitchell Duneier · 1999.
- [It was that inspiration that started me to recording the first of my original improvisations, both poetical and melodical.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ain_t_But_a_Place/IRLhcVs_pJUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=PA180&printsec=frontcover)
  *Ain’t But a Place: An Anthology of African American Writings about St. Louis*; 1998.
- [and that started us to looking around a little more](https://books.google.com/books?id=F4MfAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA608&dq=%22started+us+to%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZs4eQp4KAAxUBIX0KHSKuCGYQ6AF6BAgEEAI)
  Wilmott R. Hastings of Lynn, Massachusettes, 1898.
  Pulp and Paper Investigation Hearings
  April 25, 1908-Feb. 19, 1909, with Indices · Volume 1, Issues 1-17;
  By United States. Congress. House. Select Committee Under House Resolution 344, James Robert Mann · 1908
- [I set my teeth together hard every time those playful brutes started us to rolling.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Youth_s_Companion/Q4W7-goi_64C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+us+to%22&pg=PA200&printsec=frontcover)
  *The Youth’s Companion*, Volume 75, 1901. Originally published 1827.
- [And that, of course, gave us an insight of transportation and started us to
  thinking very seriously of being a little more independent in our transportation.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Chesapeake_Delaware_Canal_Co/JGEvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+us+to%22&pg=PA89&printsec=frontcover)
   United States. Congress. Senate. Committee on Coast and Insular Survey · 1914
- [You think that is what started us to looking into this intensive farming?](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hearings_Held_Before_the_Special_Committ/ZGsxAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)
  United States. Congress. House. Special Committee on Investigation of American Sugar Refining Company · 1911
- [The war with Spain started us to growing and we could not help it if we
  would. Our growth has made new problems , but the American people have
  faced them and will continue to face them.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Public/DClHAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)
  *The Public: A Journal of Democracy* · Volume 4 1901, originally published 1898.
- [What started us to talking about going down they broke one end of that car they broke the other.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Railway_Master_Mechanic/QSY2AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0&bsq=%22started%20us%20to%22)
  *Railway Master Mechanic*, Volume 25, 1901, originally published 1880.
- [The weather was then warm, which started them to brooding. April was very
  cold, with frosts near to zero, which killed a great many. The summer was
  very dry and hot, and the flowers did not last long.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Bee_Journal/zcW4AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+them+to%22&pg=RA1-PA124&printsec=frontcover)
  *American Bee Journal*, Volumes 3-4 1868, originally published 1861.
- [I, by short marches, got down into the country where the guerrillas were
  concentrated, and after three or four skirmishes started them to running,
  and in the pursuit nearly every horse I had started out with gave out ...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_War_of_the_Rebellion/rcFZAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+them+to%22&pg=PA229&printsec=frontcover)
  *The War of the Rebellion: A Compilation of the Official Records of the Union and Confederate Armies*, 1892, originally published 1869.
- [It was during the time that he was agent that he bought them mules or wagons and started them to farming.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Affairs_of_the_Mexican_Kickapoo_Indians/p0AvAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+them+to%22&pg=PA1365&printsec=frontcover)
  Affairs of the Mexican Kickapoo Indians: November 11 to December 7, 1907
  United States. Congress. Senate. Committee on Indian Affairs · 1908.
- [The prisoners were carried to the fields where they pulled up the weeds and
  loaded them on wagons and hauled them to the turn-rows where they could be
  destroyed, for if they were pulled up and thrown back upon the ground, the
  rains over night would have started them to growing afresh.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal/F89MAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+them+to%22&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover)
  Journal, Volumes 2-3; By Texas. Legislature. Senate · 1914, originally published 1854.
- [He sorted out a shovel and pick, made Texas Pete carry them right along
  the trail a quarter, and started him to diggin’ a hole ..](https://www.google.com/books/edition/McClure_s_Magazine/YIMk23hrSGIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22started+him+to%22&dq=%22started+him+to%22&printsec=frontcover)
  *McClure’s Magazine*, Volume 26, 1905; originally published 1893.
- [There’s a fellow up in Chicago who started me to thinking — which is dangerous business for a “rattler” like me, liable to drop a crown sheet and become unconscious at any time! Anyhow this fellow from the Windy City has been...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Railway_Review/s3TF2XHqmEkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=PA23&printsec=frontcover)
  *Railway Review*, Volume 60; 1917, originally published 1896.
- [Well, I don’t know just what stretched across the mouth of a steep,
  started me to connecting up Garber’s dangerous little gully — to keep the
  cattle absence and the Y. & C. Ř . robbery, but, from straying in through
  and maybe anyway...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Adventure/P0RzrgMR29cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=RA5-PA108&printsec=frontcover)
  Adventure, Volume 21, Issues 4-6.  1913; originally published 1910.
- [A couple of days later a tramp started me to thinking about Carter steamer
  dropped anchor, and Marie and protective coloration at the same Carlotti
  came ashore.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Collier_s/kCI-AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=RA20-PA51&printsec=frontcover)
  *Collier’s*, Incorporating Features of the American Magazine · Volume 64, 1919; originally published 1905.
- [And I jist want to tell you what started me to thinkin’ in this here
  direction. But before I begin on that ar’, I want to tell you that I had
  jist one of the best women that ever wore a bonnet, and as good lookin’ as
  any of your
  ...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Mysterious_Parchment/i4lIAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22jist+want+to+tell+you%22&pg=PA201&printsec=frontcover)
  *The Mysterious Parchment*, Joel Wakeman · 1856.
- [The knowledge of the tragedy of Grace Hollister started me to seeking
  restlessly, on bookshelves and elsewhere, for a secret that forever eluded
  me, and forever led me
  on.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Far_Country_Volume_1_of_2_EasyRead_Sup/WRRdEEW2QcoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=PA60&printsec=frontcover)
  *A Far Country* (Volume 1 of 2), By Winston Churchill · 1915.
- [That started me to watching for caterpillars and eggs out of doors, and
  friends of my work began carrying them to
  me.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Moths_of_the_Limberlost/ooclDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+me+to%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover)
  *Moths of the Limberlost*, Gene Stratton-Porter, 1912.
- [It is an in-duty at $1.684 capital invested on the strength of that
  protection jury to every American industry, and I can not understand how to
  the industry - and started it to going, and you are now going to
  our](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Congressional_Record/YAlgErIvGI0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22started+it+to%22&pg=PA337&printsec=frontcover)
  Congressional Record; Proceedings and Debates of the ... Congress · Volume
  37; By United States. Congress · 1903; originally published 1873.

### Selected Rewrites

And here are some transformations on those that preserve their sense:

- What started me to doing this was that this guy named Cowboy wanted to go somewhere and he didn’t have nobody to watch his stuff.
- What got me started doing this was that this guy named Cowboy wanted to go somewhere and he didn’t have nobody to watch his stuff.
- What got me to start doing this was that this guy named Cowboy wanted to go somewhere and he didn’t have nobody to watch his stuff.
- What got me to start to do this was that this guy named Cowboy wanted to go somewhere and he didn’t have nobody to watch his stuff.

- That started me to watching for caterpillars and eggs out of doors, and friends of my work began carrying them to me.
- That got me started watching for caterpillars and eggs out of doors, and friends of my work began carrying them to me.
- That got me to start watching for caterpillars and eggs out of doors, and friends of my work began carrying them to me.
- That got me to start to watch for caterpillars and eggs out of doors, and friends of my work began carrying them to me.

- It was that inspiration that started me to recording the first of my original improvisations, both poetical and melodical.
- That was the inspiration that got me started recording the first of my original improvisations, both poetical and melodical.
- It was that inspiration that got me to start recording the first of my original improvisations, both poetical and melodical.
- It was that inspiration that got me to start to record the first of my original improvisations, both poetical and melodical.
- That was the inspiration that got me to start to record the first of my original improvisations, both poetical and melodical.

- And that started us to looking around a little more.
- And that got us started looking around a little more.
- And that got us to start looking around a little more.
- And that got us to start to look around a little more.
- And that made us start looking around a little more.
- And that made us start to look around a little more.

- The weather was then warm, which started them to brooding.
- The weather was then warm, which got them started to brood.
- The weather was then warm, which got them started brooding.
- The weather was then warm, which got them to start to brood.
- The weather was then warm, which got them to start to brood.
- The weather was then warm, which made them start to brood.
- The weather was then warm, which made them start brooding.

- I set my teeth together hard every time those playful brutes started us to rolling.
- I set my teeth together hard every time those playful brutes got us started rolling.
- I set my teeth together hard every time those playful brutes got us to start rolling.
- I set my teeth together hard every time those playful brutes made us start rolling.

- The rains over night would have started them to growing afresh.
- The overnight rains would have gotten them started growing afresh.
- The overnight rains would have gotten them to start growing afresh.
- The overnight rains would have made them start growing afresh.
- The overnight rains would have made them start to grow afresh.

Comment: This is the most thorough, clear answer I have ever had about a grammatical doubt. Thank you very much, Chris, for taking the time to explain this. I now understand why my interpretation was incorrect. It’s only recently I’ve taken the time to make use of  English Stack Exchange and I must say I’m seriously impressed by the scholarly answers many people provide, such as yours. I want to congratulate the team behind this amazing mine of knowledge and its community.

Answer (score 4):

Usage in this area (whether or not to include ***to*** between ***start*** and a *gerund*<sup>1</sup>) has changed significantly over time. Until a century ago, we were [as likely to include the "extraneous" ***to*** as not...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started%20me%20to%20thinking%2Cstarted%20me%20thinking&year_start=1850&year_end=1919&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

But [we almost never do that today...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=started%20me%20to%20thinking%2Cstarted%20me%20thinking&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

[image]

Obviously it's ridiculous to suppose that the "rules of grammar" changed during this period. It's just *idiomatic preference* that changed. But unless you want to sound "weird", you should definitely side with the majority.

---

<sup>1</sup> ***gerund*** erroneously called a ***continuous participle*** in the first version of this answer. But is that any reason for a downvote? Perhaps I should just save myself some grief and copy those smart linguists who call them ***-ing** verb forms.*

Comment: What do you mean by "idiomatic preference"? And how can you make a statement like "until a century ago" based on data that doesn't go back to before 1855? Not that the statement is incorrect -- just that your data is limited. Finally, your data covers only the printed word.  What if I told you that I personally know "mountain folk" who would say "started them to moving" even today? They're not "weird"; they just happen to speak with a regional dialect that has not been "educated out" of them.

Comment: 'Rules of grammar' are not fixed, but usage-driven (if rather more slowly in general than definitions of words are).

Comment: @Tim: The possibility that you know "mountain folk" who *still* use the outdated verb form isn't really relevant. *Most* native Anglophones (including me) would think the usage was at least *slightly* odd, and only a really daft non-native speaker would want to unwittingly use a "generally recognised as outdated" expression if they could just as easily learn the current mainstream standard version.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: For them the speech pattern isn't "outdated" at all. It's how they have always talked and how they will continue to talk.  Why should they learn to talk like city folk?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not running down dialectal speakers at all, nor am I suggesting they should change their speech patterns. I'm simply pointing out that few if any *learners* would want to be "accidentally" picking up non-standard usages. Not least because *some* native speakers do in fact harbour prejudices against people who don't talk the way they do. And "mainstream" English is just that - it's not "how city folk talk".

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following:

> The wind started the windmill spinning.

We have **started** with a direct object **the windmill** and a non-finite complement **spinning**, which is what the windmill was doing.

Now consider:

> The wind **caused** the windmill **to spin**.

Again, a direct object **the windmill** and a non-finite complement, **to spin**.

What we have in the quote from Steinbeck is a kind of hybrid, where a non-finite clause that doesn't need **to** has it nonetheless, and the complement is in a form that the standard use of **started** does not license:

> ... to spinning.

It's regional talk.

Compare "start them to moving" here:
https://www.google.com/books/edition/Experiences_of_a_Trapper_and_Hunter/UbbZ6ThFkAQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22them+to+moving%22&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover

Comment: What rubbish! Whether you call it a continuous participle or a gerund, the ***-ing*** form was rarely used in "verb-based complement" until the mid-1800s. And *since* then there's been an idiomatic free-for-all as to which verbs stick with the infinitive *(**afford, agree, arrange, ask, begin,...**)* and those that embraced the continuous *(**admnit, avoid, consider,...**)* - plus those thsat swing either way *(**hate, like, love, prefer,...**)*. But the distinction is effectively ***arbitrary*** - there are no special syntactic rules beyond "idiomacy" in play here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I didn't call it a continuous participle or a gerund.  It was Lambie making that distinction. I referred to it as a non-finite complement.

Comment: What is your evidence for "until the mid-1800s"? Just curious what you're consulting. When I posted my answer,  I got a message warning me to cite some authority or risk having my answer deleted.

Comment: And are you saying that my claim that Steinbeck is using dialect here is rubbish?  Really?

Comment: Hoyle (1788) **...to prevent the ball *rolling off***  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hoyle_s_Games_Improved/QAJeAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+ball+rolling%22&pg=PA189&printsec=frontcover

Comment: I'm certainly saying that *Evening of a hot day started the little wind to moving among the leaves* isn't (and imho never was) "dialect". That extraneous ***to*** might have been a little old-fashioned even when it was written, but I've no reason to suppose Steinbeck wanted his narrative style there to be rustic or dialectal.

Comment: The narrator uses slang like "jungle up", a verb that refers to migrants congregating in "hobo jungles" or encampments.  The narrator has his  idiom too.

Comment: I didn't know "jungle-up", so I had to look it up in the full OED to find the dedicated entry **jungle** (verb) *To prepare a meal at a hoboes' camp; to form such a camp; to join forces with another person. **Usually with up.*** But the OED doesn't even mark it as informal or slang, and it's certainly not "dialect". Anyway, surely @tchrist's exhaustive Answer makes the relevant points far better than anything I can write in comments.